# Flex children not filling parent container when flex-basis is set to 0

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm dealing with a 4 column grid that has a variable number of items. The grid is responsive so instead of using pixel/em values I'm using percentages in combination with `calc` to compensate for the right margin.

To ensure that the remaining boxes of an uneven row don't resize and fill the remaining space I set my flex-basis property to 0. The only problem that remains is the boxes themselves are a few pixels short of filling the parent container (notice how the items don't horizontally fill the entire grid). How can I fix this?

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.container {

}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 6px);
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.flex-child:not(:nth-of-type(4n)) {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">1</div>
  <div class="flex-child">2</div>
  <div class="flex-child">3</div>
  <div class="flex-child">4</div>
  <div class="flex-child">5</div>
  <div class="flex-child">6</div>
  <div class="flex-child">7</div>
  <div class="flex-child">8</div>
  <div class="flex-child">9</div>
  <div class="flex-child">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Looks like it's doing what you want: http://imgur.com/JSVOL5x

Comment: Notice how the boxes aren't horizontally filling the entire container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the `right margin` to say `8px`.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.container {

}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 6px);
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.flex-child:not(:nth-of-type(4n)) {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">1</div>
  <div class="flex-child">2</div>
  <div class="flex-child">3</div>
  <div class="flex-child">4</div>
  <div class="flex-child">5</div>
  <div class="flex-child">6</div>
  <div class="flex-child">7</div>
  <div class="flex-child">8</div>
  <div class="flex-child">9</div>
  <div class="flex-child">10</div>
  <div class="flex-child">11</div>
  <div class="flex-child">12</div>
  <div class="flex-child">13</div>
  <div class="flex-child">14</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I literally just discovered this seconds before you posted. Is there any explanation for this though? Mathematically speaking?

Comment: You are cutting 6px of each div, even the fourth one, and then return less width with the margin. 6x4=24 vs 6x3=18. By increasing the margin to 8px you ensure the gap you make with the width is filled.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation.